# Django Postgres table partitioning not working with 'pgpartition' command

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have a huge "Logs" postgres table being used extensively in my Django project.
Logs table has more than 20 million records and its slowing down the queries and page load time is also increased.
I am using below Django and Postgres versions:-
Django: 4.0
Postgres: 13

I read about table partitioning and decided to use "django-postgres-extra" as I don't want to manage migration files.

I followed all the steps mentioned in below link but I am not able to create partitioned tables using "pgpartition" command.
https://django-postgres-extra.readthedocs.io/en/master/table_partitioning.html

Am I missing something here?
models.py changes:-

```
from django.db import models

from psqlextra.types import PostgresPartitioningMethod
from psqlextra.models import PostgresPartitionedModel
from psqlextra.manager import PostgresManager


class Logs(PostgresPartitionedModel):

    class PartitioningMeta:
        method = PostgresPartitioningMethod.RANGE
        key = ["ctime"]

    objects = PostgresManager()

    ctime = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    logname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    builds = models.ForeignKey(Build)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    'psqlextra',
    'logs',
]


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'psqlextra.backend', 
        'NAME': 'logdb',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'crypt',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}

PSQLEXTRA_PARTITIONING_MANAGER = 'logs.partition.manager'
```

Created a file named 'partition' under logs app and defined a manager object as per doc link above.
partition.py

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from logs.models import Logs

from psqlextra.partitioning import (
    PostgresPartitioningManager,
    PostgresCurrentTimePartitioningStrategy,
    PostgresTimePartitionSize,
    partition_by_current_time,
)
from psqlextra.partitioning.config import PostgresPartitioningConfig

manager = PostgresPartitioningManager([

    # 3 partitions ahead, each partition is one month
    # delete partitions older than 6 months
    # partitions will be named `[table_name]_[year]_[3-letter month name]`.
    PostgresPartitioningConfig(
        model=Logs,
        strategy=PostgresCurrentTimePartitioningStrategy(
            size=PostgresTimePartitionSize(months=1),
            count=1,
            max_age=relativedelta(months=1),
        ),
    ),
])
```

When I ran "python manage.py pgmakemigrations" command it created a migration file as below:-
0002_alter_log_managers.py

```
# Generated by Django 4.0.3 on 2022-05-19 12:22

from django.db import migrations
import psqlextra.manager.manager


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('logs', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterModelManagers(
            name='logs',
            managers=[
                ('objects', psqlextra.manager.manager.PostgresManager()),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

But as soon as I run "pgpartition" command I get below error:-

## python manage.py pgpartition

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/party/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/user/party/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psqlextra/management/commands/pgpartition.py", line 72, in handle
    plan = partitioning_manager.plan(
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psqlextra/partitioning/manager.py", line 52, in plan
    model_plan = self._plan_for_config(
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psqlextra/partitioning/manager.py", line 84, in _plan_for_config
    table = self._get_partitioned_table(connection, config.model)
  File "/home/user/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psqlextra/partitioning/manager.py", line 121, in _get_partitioned_table
    raise PostgresPartitioningError(
psqlextra.partitioning.error.PostgresPartitioningError: Model Logs, with table logs_logs does not exists in the database. Did you run `python manage.py migrate`?
```

Not sure what I am missing here...

Comment: I don't use `python manage.py pgpartition`.  So I don't know about it. 
But After you run `python manage.py pgmakemigration`, did you try `python manage.py migrate` ? 

if it works, then. you need to add value for range partition.
[https://django-postgres-extra.readthedocs.io/en/master/table_partitioning.html#adding-a-range-partition](https://django-postgres-extra.readthedocs.io/en/master/table_partitioning.html#adding-a-range-partition)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "django-postgres-extra" is only used for declarative partitioning. i.e. When we anticipate that a table might grow big in size in future then we can use declaration partitioning while creating table at the very beginning.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-DECLARATIVE

So I am dropping the idea for now and trying to improve performance by adding more indexes and using caching etc..